# Microsoft Print to PDF file missing / disappeared - where did it go?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, pdf, filesystems, print-to-pdf

I'm trying to print a particular web page to PDF using "Microsoft Print to PDF" on Windows 10.
When the `Save Print Output As` dialog comes up, I find that it's browsed to the (empty or near-empty) folder I want to store the file in.
I paste in the name, copied from near the top of the website I'm printing.
I press Save, and the dialog disappears, and everything proceeds with apparent success.
This is different from the situation where I've tried putting an invalid character like a colon in the filename, when an error message pops up with the file name and a message that "the file name is not valid."
However, when I later check the target folder, the file is not there!

I have all files visible (including hidden files and operating system files) so it's not that there's some messed-up file extension or property.  I've tried this in an empty and near-empty folder so it's not just that I'm missing it in a long list.  What's happening here?

Comment: Check the read to configure printer - https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/print-pdf-windows/

Comment: That article is about installing a PDF printer.  This question assumes that part has already been done, for the "Microsoft Print to PDF" default that the article discusses how to install.  The article does not address the issue in this question, though people who don't have that already installed can read the article to learn how.

Answer (score 2):

Certain characters, which are legal in filenames, still mess up Microsoft Print to PDF and produce a silent failure.
For example, a comma.
If you have one of these in there, take it out of the filename and try again.

Comment: What type of answer is it? Why don't you edit the question?

Comment: This is the answer to the question for at least some cases.  I had the question for a while before I found this answer, and thought it might be useful to others who might have the same question. You may want to [read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/287315) instead of just downvoting both because you disagree with StackExchange encouraged practice.